# Trying to duplicate my Android Studio project and make it run

Tags: android, android-studio, copy, project

Working on an Android app for a university course. I want to make a duplicate so I can add new code/modules without breaking anything. I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045964/android-studio-how-to-copy-a-project) but it did not work for me, I get this error:

Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_2_apk was defined multiple times.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

I click on OK to uninstall the app but it keeps failing to uninstall.

What am I missing and what should I do to make the duplicate work?

Comment: To Resolve the error, I just went to the Build menu and clicked on the Rebuild option. Works fine now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just Build-->clean project....