# How do I update the build.gradle script names when cloning a project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, build.gradle, cloning

There's a great description on how to copy a project in Android Studio, which I followed with 99% success: [Android Studio - How to copy a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045964/android-studio-how-to-copy-a-project)

However, there is one small sticking point I'm worried will bite me in the butt later -- In the project structure panel, the build.gradle scripts still refer to the old version of the project (GPS_Mark3) instead of the new one (GPS_Mark4). I have tried refactor / renaming everything I can think of, rebuilding the project, cleaning the project, syncing with Gradle files, closing / reopening the IDE... How can I fix this? Or, is it just a weird quirk I should forget about and doesn't matter?

[Here's what I'm talking about in an image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWpsW.png)

Comment: Check your `settings.gradle` file and see if the name shows up there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you CommonsWare for the speedy comment!! You nailed it. I checked the settings. gradle file and changed the rootProject.name to reflect the name update to my app.